# Accessing a CONST attribute of series of Classes

Tags: php, oop

This is how I wanted to do it which would work in PHP 5.3.0+

```
<?php
    class MyClass
    {
        const CONSTANT = 'Const var';        
    }

    $classname = 'MyClass';
    echo $classname::CONSTANT; // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

But I'm restricted to using PHP 5.2.6. Can anyone think of a simple way to simulate this behavior without instantiating the class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this without using [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) in pre-5.3 code. Just use the [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'Const var';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo constant("$classname::CONSTANT");

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutly need to access a constant like that, you can do this:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
        const CONSTANT = 'Const var';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo eval( 'return '.$classname.'::CONSTANT;' );
?>
```

But, if i were you, I'd try not to use eval.